# Flutter/Dart - FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java - Build fails with Exception "error: cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

After upgrading to Null Safety `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"` I'm getting errors when I try to build my Flutter app in Android Studio.

```
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-9.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class FirebaseInstanceId
      location: package com.google.firebase.iid
    C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-9.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    import com.google.firebase.iid.Metadata;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class Metadata
      location: package com.google.firebase.iid
    C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-9.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:152: error: cannot find symbol
                      : Metadata.getDefaultSenderId(FirebaseApp.getInstance());
                        ^
      symbol:   variable Metadata
      location: class FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin
    C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-9.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:153: error: cannot find symbol
              FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteToken(senderId, "*");
              ^
      symbol:   variable FirebaseInstanceId
      location: class FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin
    C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-9.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:165: error: cannot find symbol
                      : Metadata.getDefaultSenderId(FirebaseApp.getInstance());
                        ^
      symbol:   variable Metadata
      location: class FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin
    C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-9.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:166: error: cannot find symbol
              String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(senderId, "*");
                             ^
      symbol:   variable FirebaseInstanceId
      location: class FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin
```

Android Studio tells me FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java "cannot find symbol". So what does this mean and how do I fix it

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: I tried to fork & clone the project in order to change the outdated dependencies in pubspec.yaml. But this is my first time and I don't understand why "pub get" is not downloading the plugin into my external libraries folder in my Flutter app.

Comment: The plugin creator/maintainer has just updated the plugin to veriosn 3.05.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Update your `firebase_messaging` in pusbpec.yaml to version that supports null-safety (for example: `firebase_messaging: ^10.0.0`, and call `flutter pub get from` terminal

Comment: I've using the latest fcm_config: 3.0.4 in pubspec.yaml which must have  firebase_messaging-9.1.4 bundled in it. But I have no idea how to upgrade it.

Comment: When I do a pub outdated I get this as outdated transitive dependencies. But as I said I have no idea how to upgrade it;                                                          
          firebase_messaging                     *9.1.4   *9.1.4      *9.1.4      10.0.0  
firebase_messaging_platform_interface  *2.1.4   *2.1.4      *2.1.4      3.0.0   
firebase_messaging_web                 *1.0.7   *1.0.7      *1.0.7      2.0.0

Comment: I tried forking the original repository and updating the pubspec.yaml to include the new updated firebase but a "pub get" tells me there's no pubspec.yaml

Comment: Seems cloning the repository leaves me one level up from where the pubspec.yaml exists. Any idea how I can point the entry one level up? Here's the entry;    fcm_config:
    git:
      url: "https://github.com/meghead/fcm_config.git"

Comment: Did you try to override dependency in your project pubspec.yaml?

Comment: The fork I created doesn't download anything into External Libraries/Dart Packages even though it doesn't return an error when I do a pub get for pubspec.yaml

Comment: It's not possible to override the dependency in pubspec.yaml because the Firebase messaging dependencies exist not in my pubspec.yaml but the pubspec.yaml of the FCMConfig project/repository.

Comment: Turns out the plugin creator/maintainer has just updated the plugin.

Comment: This worked for me.. thanks sir. At first I was using   firebase_messaging:  in pubspec.aml file but it was throwing this error. But after adding the latest version number to it, it worked,   firebase_messaging: ^10.0.6

Answer (score 2):

First, get the latest versions of your firebase dependencies from pub.dev

Run the commands:

```
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub get
flutter clean
```

Invalidate caches and restart

and then try running the app

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that I updated androidx core version from 1.0.1 to 1.5.0 in my `app/gradle` file but I didn't update it in project level gradle file in `resolutionStrategy`

[image]

[image]

They both should be the same.